# Can you really prove anything from a contradiction, or is that only restricted to formulas?

Tags: logic

Let's assume that A∧¬A is provable. It's easy to see how any proposition is provable from that assumption. But since you can prove anything from a contradiction, can you also prove the proposition that "∧A∧ is a formula"? If a statement about the formal system is true, does that reflect on what that formal system is actually like? And if so, does that mean that A∧¬A ⊢ ∧A∧?

Comment: if the deductive system is typical, then no. Most deductive systems are defined over propositions, further they have no notion of "formula" - that a string is a formula is typically a metalinguistic judgement.

Comment: You have the wrong context.  From a contradiction any CONCLUSION will be valid. Valid here does not mean true in reality. Valid simply means the premises cannot be true while the premises are false ---that would be impossible to do.  Truth in the real world is a different matter.  You cannot use a formula that relies on syntax as a random conclusion because how would it be relevant? That would be a non sequitur.  /\A /\ is meaningless in Mathematical logic which is what you are using. The syntax matters.

Comment: @Papuseme Is "∧A∧ is a formula" not a proposition? It can be true or false, and that's all it takes for a sentence to be a proposition. I'd like to hear a more detailed answer on this if you have the time please.

Comment: @Logikal I don't see how what you said answers the question.

Comment: Am I right if I assume that your question tries to ask whether in formal systems in which contradictory statements can be both true and any conclusion from that valid, you can even conclude meta-logical conclusions, ie. change the syntactic rules of the system, as it were?

Comment: Yes, it is restricted to formulas and that is not a formula of the language: formulas are specified according to the syntactical rules. The formal concept of derivation is defined for formulas.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking More or less, yes. I am asking whether if you assume a contradiction, you can prove that something which isn't a formula is a formula. And then, since any formula is provable from a contradiction, whether that means that A∧¬A ⊢ ∧A∧

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but is "∧A∧ is a formula" not a proposition? If it is, it is provable from a contradiction. So since it is true that ∧A∧ is a formula under this assumption, why isn't A∧¬A ⊢ ∧A∧ the case?

Comment: You are mixing formulas of the formal system and statements about the formal system.

Comment: You are probably right, but I would like to know why this doesn't work. If a statement about the formal system is true, why does that not reflect on what that formal system is actually like?

Comment: This is pretty introductory stuff. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion

Comment: One should distinguish the object language from the metalanguage. If a theory in the object language explodes then all wffs are theorems and the theory is useless. If you assert that your metalanguage is subject to classical logic and claim that some contradiction holds there, then that will explode and everything that can be said about the object language, including what counts as a wff, will be true. At this point, your metalanguage is also useless, so the whole exercise becomes pointless. Using an explosive logic *is* a commitment not to allow any true contradiction on pain of triviality.

Comment: @Bumble it isn't useless. There is a certain formal system in which if the premise is consistent, then a certain conclusion will be provable from it. And if that premise isn't consistent, then that conclusion isn't even a well formed formula. It's a very weird system, but this is why my question is really important.

Comment: @NickDoe, Bumble and Mauro have it about right. "xyz" is a formula is a proposition, but it is not a proposition of the object language, hence a metalinguistic judgement.

Comment: Gosh, wasn't this covered in *Goedel, Escher, Bach* like. 40 years ago?

Answer (score 1):

A formal logic is generally defined in several parts. First, you have an alphabet of symbols like 'a', 'x', '&', '->' where the symbols are given syntactic categories such as constant, variable, etc. Then you have a set of well-formed formulas (WFFs) over this alphabet. For example:

1. If p is a predicate symbol and F is a constant symbol or variable, then p(F) is a WFF.
2. if P and Q are WFFs, then P&Q is a WFF.

Etc. Then *after* the notion of a WFF is defined, you define rules of inference which always map a set of WFFs into another WFF. That's the essential bit: a rule of inference can only produce a WFF as output.

When someone says that from a contradiction, you can derive any proposition, what they mean is that the rules of inference allow you to derive any proposition from a contradiction. But the rules of inference can only produce WFFs, there is no rule that can derive something that is not a WFF, so what that means is that any WFF can be derived from a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does it tie into the fact that we can derive a true statement about the formal system? Does that just have no consequence on what the formal system is actually like?

Comment: @NickDoe, I'm sorry, I don't get what you are asking in that comment.

Comment: Well as you say, any formula is provable from a contradiction. That includes every proposition. So the proposition that "∧A∧ is a formula" is also provable from the contradiction. Does this have no effect on what the formal system is actually like under our assumption?

Comment: @NickDoe, Ah! Yes, I suppose if you created a theory of strings in the formal system, including a notion of which strings were WFFs in the formal system itself, and then you introduced a contradiction, you could derive for any string S the theorem that the string is a WFF. But that theorem would itself be an actual WFF. You couldn't derive something that is not a WFF.